# emerge naked/nakedly

Tags: secondary-predicates

From an American sitcom Friends S05E17, [SOURCE HERE](http://www.livesinabox.com/friends/season5/517rik.htm)

> Suspect has just emerged naked from the sewer.

I just wonder why it is "naked" instead of "nakedly". Normally it's the adverb that modifies a verb. Such as: "I went there *happily*." It would be wrong if you say "I went there happy."

Is it just because it's colloquial, and couldn't be used in formal English? But the quoted sentence seems right to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a predicate adjective, not an adverb.  It doesn't modify the verb.  It's not the way they emerged.  Instead, it predicates on the subject *suspect*, describing the state they're in as they emerged.

The adverb *nakedly* would be inappropriate, since *nakedly* isn't generally a way that people do things; *naked* is a state they're in when they do things.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that "I went there happy" and "I went there happily" can both be correct, they just have slightly different meanings. As you say, "happy" would refer to the state you were in while you went there, and "happily" refers to the way you did it. So the OP's perhaps basing their understanding on a misconception. At any rate, +1! (And if you want to edit in something about "happy", I'll delete this comment.)